# Can a European apply for a Chinese tourist visa at the consulate in Macau?

Tags: visas, china, macau

Can a Spanish national with a valid passport who is in Macau as a tourist apply at the Chinese consulate in Macau for a tourist visa?

I was reading information online but seems the rules change quite quickly. Anyone did it recently?

Answer (score 5):

I've never done it in Macau, but do it all the time in HK. There is no Chinese consulate, either in HK or Macau (consulates are for foreign countries, and these 2 places are in China). What you have is a Chinese Affairs office.

As a tourist, you can apply in HK (you will get one or two entries, nothing better, though), and, since things work out generally the same in both SARs, I would imagine you could do it there too. However, I would recommend to go through a travel agency. The Chinese Affairs office usually asks for a lot of documentation, and travel agencies specializing in Chinese visas are usually very good at handling that. I've seen many in Macau, advertising Chinese visa services. Enquire with one of them.

If everything else fails, come to HK, and do it there. But since China Travel Service has branches in Macau, you should be fine.